# What algorithm do i need to solve my problem?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

unfortunately I even don't know what kind of problem I deal with. But I'll try to explain as good as I can and maybe you can tell what kind of problem this is and how to solve it.

I want to find sets, that potentially can be decomposed into smaller sets by combining overlaying sets, so that a single element can be calculated.

The following chart on the left side shows the most simple example. Subtraction of the sum of all elements ob B from A yields to the value of X4. I've found already an algorithm to search for those sets.

Problem is on the right side: Even though it's obvious that the sum of the A sets minus the sum of the B sets yields also to X4, I'm totally stuck with finding an algorithm for nested structures.

[image: Examples of problem]

p.s.: i've thousands of sets in a SQL database

Comment: This smells of partitioning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Maybe when a user with far more experience than you in what fits the [elementary-set-theory] tag removes the tag it means that you may have the wrong idea about this question fitting such tag.

Comment: @Asaf: Sorry! I have not seen that i was removed by an expert. I thought i forgot it ... Sorry again! Now i removed it again.

Comment: Are you trying to find elements in one set that are NOT IN any of the other sets?

Comment: @user137481: No - I'm trying to find (combinations of) sets that can be subtracted from other (combinations of) sets, so that single elements are left over.

Comment: Suppose you have n sets. You realize that there are a total of $2^n$ possible combinations? That means you would be trying to compute $C_i - C_j$ where $C_i$ and $C_j$ are each one of the possible $2^n$ set combinations. If that is really what you want to do, you will be waiting a very long time for the algorithm to complete.

Comment: On the other hand, suppose you ask a different question. Let's say you have a set $S$. You want to know if there is some combination (i.e. union) of the other sets $C$ such that S - C contains only 1 element. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Depending on the nature of your sets, it may not even be possible. If you have a subset with two elements that are unique to that subset, you're stuck, because you can't split them apart by subtracting other sets.

Comment: @user137481: That's the reason why I hope there exists a algorithm to avoid calculating all possible combinations.

Comment: @John: It's ok if it does not work. I'm only interested in those sets where it would work.

Comment: @user137481: Yes - and i have no idea how to find the unions of the other sets C. And worse, also the set S can be a union of sets.

Comment: Are you trying find just one possible $C_i - C_j$ that gives you a single element or all of the possibilities?

Comment: @user137481: All of those with a single element left over.

Comment: I meant do you need just one $C_i$ and one $C_j$ or all possible $C_i$ and $C_j$?

Comment: @user137481: Hmmm ... Sorry, I suppose I don't understand the question. I'll have to leave now the house and be right back later - Sorry and Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila My interpretiotn of what the OP is asking. Suppose we have n sets $S_1, S_2, ..., S_n$. Let $A=${$S_1$, $S_2$,...$S_n$}. Let $C_i$ and $C_j$ be a subset of A. Find all $C_i - C_j$ that yield only a single element. I'm not a set theorist but it looks like you are. The OP is asking whether there is an efficient way of figuring out all possible $C_i$ and $C_j$ or is brute force the only way?

Comment: @user137481: Yes, and that's not a set theory question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe the OP should post his question on Computer Science Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after our phone discussion, I guess that your problem can be formalized like this. Please feel free to correct the problem formulation. All other members, feel free to correct or improve the solution idea.

**Problem.**

Given index sets $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_m \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ and real numbers $s_1,\dots,s_m \in \mathbb{R}$, try to recover as many entries of an unknown real vector $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as possible, given the information that
$$ \sum_{j \in A_i} x_j = s_i  \mbox{ for all } i = 1,\dots, m. $$

**Solution Idea.**

Compute the *general solution* to the following system of linear equations: 
$$ \sum_{j \in A_i} x_j = s_i  \mbox{ for all } i = 1,\dots, m. $$
Let the solution be denoted by
$$x^* = a _0 + \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i a_i $$
for vectors $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and scalars $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

The entry $x_i$ of the unknown vector $x$ is reconstructable if and only if the i-th entries of the vectors $a_1,\dots,a_k$ are all zero. Then, the value of $x_i$ is the i-th entry of $a_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Create lists for each element, in which it is present(this can be done while assigning elements to "your" sets), for e.g.:
$$list\_x_1={A_1,B_1}\\list\_x_2=A_1,B_2\\list\_x_3=A_1,B_3\\\color{red}{list\_x_4=A_1}\\list\_x_5=A_2,B_1\\\cdots\\list\_x_{16}=A_4,B_4$$ 
Notice the elemnts you require has only one corresponding element int the list, So linearly search for lists with only one element.

Comment: With this method I can find elements that are only in one set. I already know how to achieve that. The problem is how i can find the corresponding combination of sets. Sorry that my question made that not clear enough.